# Flutter- How to open phone gallery?

Tags: dart, flutter

I want to open gallery directory here, I am using this code but is showing all
option I want to open the only gallery.

```
List images;
  int maxImageNo = 10;
  bool selectSingleImage = false;
  File _imageFile;
  _pickImageFromGallery() async {
    File file;
    String result;
    try {
      result = await FlutterImagePickCrop.pickAndCropImage(_gallery);
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      result = e.message;
      print(e.message);
    }
    if (!mounted) return;

    setState(() {
      imageFile = new File(result);
      _platformMessage = result;
    });}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you only want to select from the Gallery, then you can use the [image_picker](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/image_picker) plugin. If cropping is important to you, then I'll reconsider my answer as `image_picker` doesn't provide that.

```
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  File _image;

  Future getImage() async {
    var image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);

    setState(() {
      _image = image;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('Image Picker Example'),
      ),
      body: new Center(
        child: _image == null
            ? new Text('No image selected.')
            : new Image.file(_image),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: getImage,
        tooltip: 'Pick Image',
        child: new Icon(Icons.add_a_photo),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It's the standard image picker UI. The default display is recents, but the "hamburger" menu gives the user access to Photos, Downloads, Google Drive, Google Photos, etc. The appbar overflow menu also gives the user the option to open internal storage if that's available.

Comment: Is there some way we can change that standard image picker UI?